# Python (Google Sheets API) - Searching for a certain string and returning the whole row

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

so right now I have a spreadsheet that contains a list of banned players from my discord server. Right now I'm trying to create a python script that allows you to input a string/int and if it finds a match it returns the whole row.

Example of the Spreadsheet: (There will be more columns as this is just an example)

https://gyazo.com/82aee173103cbb77cff067a9e28c5fc1

So as you can see, if the user gives the discord ID, it should return the whole row which the value is on.

So far my setup:

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

scope = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds",'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]

creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("creds.json", scope)

client = gspread.authorize(creds)

sheet = client.open("MRP Blacklist Data").sheet1

values = result.get('values', [])

    if not values:
        print('No data found.')
    else:
        print('Name, Major:')
        for row in values:
            print('%s, %s' % (row[0], row[4]))
```

The code is incomplete and I have no clue how I could complete it. Any tips or suggestions would help greatly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use gspread `.find("string")` and `.row_values(n)` function.

`.find("string")` - Get the position of the cell that matches the string. It has .row and .cell properties which you can use locate the cell.

`row_values(n)` - Get all values from the given row number:

In your code:

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

scope = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds",'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("creds.json", scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)
sheet = client.open("MRP Blacklist Data").sheet1

print(sheet.row_values(sheet.find("ABC").row))
```

It will print something like this:

```
['Test1', 'TestID1', 'ABC', 'Costal Craft', 'None', 'Just Because']
```

Here's my sample data:
[image]

Note: .find() will only return the first occurrence of the string, if you want to search all the occurrence, use .findall() all loop through the list and use row_values to each element.

**.findall() example:**

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

scope = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds",'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("creds.json", scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)
sheet = client.open("MRP Blacklist Data").sheet1
values = sh.findall("ABC")
for r in values:
    print(', '.join(sh.row_values(r.row)))
```

**Output should look like this:**

```
Test1, TestID1, ABC, Costal Craft, None, Just Because
Test3, TestID3, ABC, Costal Craft, None, None
```

**Test Data:**
[image]

Reference:

[Finding a cell](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#finding-all-matched-cells)

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Is there a way to print this out normally without being in a list? Currently it sends it out like this:    ['Discord', '123456789', 'Gamertag', 'Realm Name', 'Alts', 'Ban', '9/21/2020', 'Perm', 'Perm']

Comment: Try using this `print(', '.join(sh.row_values(sh.find("ABC").row)))`

Comment: Also could you give an example with the `.findall()` method? The looping over part to be exact.

Comment: @SpaceTurtle0 - I edited my answer above and include a .findall() example.

Comment: @Nikko J. How to get only second value from Google sheet with this code?