# Python (Google Sheets API) - Searching for a certain string and returning second cell

Tags: python, google-sheets

From this question [Python (Google Sheets API) - Searching for a certain string and returning the whole row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65313107/python-google-sheets-api-searching-for-a-certain-string-and-returning-the-wh) I use code, but I need return only value from second cell (from whole row, if python some find).

I try this code:

```
sheet3 = client.open("sheet_name").worksheet('DATA')
values = sheet3.findall("1") #try find value "1" in whole sheet
for r in values:
     print(', '.join(sheet3.row_values(r.row)))
```

And I got this:

```
Pronájem bytu 3+1 74 m2 Ortenova Jihlava, https://www.fincentrumreality.com/reality/pronajem-bytu-3-1-74-m2-ortenova%2c-jihlava-16899, , , , , , , , 1
```

But i need to get only print this code:

```
https://www.fincentrumreality.com/reality/pronajem-bytu-3-1-74-m2-ortenova%2c-jihlava-16899
```

this value is in second (2.) cell in Google Sheet.

But this code not working (I got only empty print):

```
  print(', '.join(sheet3.row_values(r.row)[2]))
```

Comment: Python is zero-indexed. Try `print(sheet3.row_values(r.row)[1])` instead (you don't need the `join`).

Comment: I am "blind" ... thank you. :)