# Python (Google Sheets API) - Search for a specific row by the values of two cells and return certain cells from this row

Tags: python, google-sheets

From this question [Python (Google Sheets API) - Searching for a certain string and returning the whole row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65313107/python-google-sheets-api-searching-for-a-certain-string-and-returning-the-wh) I use code, and returning the whole row by the value of a single cell.

How can I returning the values of **two cells** and return certain cells from this row?

For example, in the attached table you need to return the values of the "values" and "actions" columns from the rows containing the cells "14.05.2021" (the "date" column) and "Bob" (the "employee"column).

[Attached table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnFNJ.jpg)

Comment: how about `row[0]` to get cell from first column ?

Comment: what did you try? Where is your code? Did you get error message? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: code uses `', '.join(sh.row_values(r.row))` to conver it to string so it means you have some list in `sh.row_values(r.row)` and you can try to use `[2]` to get third element in row- `sh.row_values(r.row)[2]`. And the same with `[3]` to get fourth element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code in your link uses `join` to convert `sh.row_values(r.row)` to string so it means you have some list in `sh.row_values(r.row)` and you can use slice to get values

```
for item in sheet.findall("14.05.2021"):
    row = sheet.row_values(item.row)
    if row[1] == 'Bob':
        print('values:',  row[2])
        print('actions:', row[3])
```

But I think it can be simpler to use it with `pandas.dataframe`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(sheet.get_all_records())

rows = df[ (df['date'] == "2021.05.14") & (df['employee'] == 'Bob') ]

print( rows )

print( rows[['values', 'actions']] )
```

---

Minimal working code. In my language (Polish) I need date `"YYYY.mm.dd"` like `"2021.05.14"` but you may need `"14.05.2021"`.

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import pandas as pd

scope = [
    "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds",
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"
]

creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("creds.json", scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)

sheet = client.open("example-data").sheet1

for item in sheet.findall("2021.05.14"):
    row = sheet.row_values(item.row)
    if row[1] == 'Bob':
        print('values:', row[2])
        print('actions:', row[3])    

df = pd.DataFrame(sheet.get_all_records())

data = df[ (df['date'] == "2021.05.14") & (df['employee'] == 'Bob') ]

print('---')
print(data)
print('---')
print(data[['values', 'actions']])
print('---')

for index, row in data.iterrows():
    print('>>> index:', index)
    print('>>> row:', row)
    print('>>> values:', row['values'])
    print('>>> actions:', row['actions'])    
    print('---')
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked! 
for my question, the following code came up
`for item in sheet.findall("14.05.2021"):
    row = sheet.row_values(item.row)
    if row[1] == 'Bob':
        print(row[2],row[3])`