# Analogue of the sheet.createTextFinder('somestr'); in Google-Sheets Python API

Tags: python, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Does Google-Sheets Python API have same function like `createTextFinder()`?
Here is a sample code for Google-Script:

```
function findINSheet(sheet, someStr){
  var tf = sheet.createTextFinder(someStr);
  return tf.findAll();
}
```

How can I write similar code in Python?

Comment: Your question is similar to this existing post answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/65313713 about "Python (Google Sheets API) - Searching for a certain string and returning the whole row".

Comment: Great. Thank you!